# How to check in PHP, if a socket still connected, if I don't have the socket handler?

Tags: php, linux, sockets, twitter

I am using a composer package [owlycode/streaming-bird](https://packagist.org/packages/owlycode/streaming-bird) to call [twitter stream API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/firehose). The stream API opens a socket between your app and twitter, to receive tweets that have a specified keyword. In my case the keyword is 'hello'.

Here is the code using owlycode/streaming-bird package:

```
 <?PHP
    $oauthToken = '';
    $oauthSecret = '';
    $consumerKey = '';
    $consumerSecret = '';

    $bird = new StreamingBird($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oauthToken, $oauthSecret);

    $bird
        ->createStreamReader(StreamReader::METHOD_FILTER)
        ->setTrack(['hello']) // Fetch every tweet containing one of the following words
        ->consume(function ($tweet) { // Now we provide a callback to execute on every received tweet.
            echo '------------------------' . "\n";
            echo $tweet['text'] . "\n";
        });
  ?>
```

My problem is when this connection is closed by error, I am unable to know that. So I am unable to reconnect with twitter again.

Is there anything in PHP that searches open sockets based on their domain name?

Maybe something like

```
  check_if_socket_open('https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/firehose.json')
```

?

Note: I cannot use [socket_get_status](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-status.php), because I don't have the socket variable.

Comment: It [looks to me](https://github.com/OwlyCode/StreamingBird/blob/master/src/StreamReader.php#L80) like it will keep reconnecting the socket if the connection is lost.

Comment: Just looking at the inline documentation, it seems like @miken32 is correct, I think the issue is the time it takes to detect a connection loss... for example: if the timeout defaults to 1 minute... then you will have lost 1 minute of the stream

Comment: Although it is a bad solution... it might be worth looking into stream_set_timeout ( $stream, $seconds ) for other reasons.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php

Comment: I can't understand why my answer is down-voted. The socket will keep reconnecting but you can set stream_set_timeout in the below function, and keep a track of the time that the last stream activity occurred. I will add consume function as well to better explain my point. The only drawback is that this is considered a core change of the class.

Comment: Does it lose connection reliably? Could it maybe be your php script itself timing out?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to check socket status, if you've no access to the socket.

If you're searching for a workaround without touching StreamBird's code, then you can make a class based on `\OwlyCode\StreamingBird`, then implement its `connect` method:

```
<?php
class MyStreamReader extends \OwlyCode\StreamingBird
{
  protected $stream;

  protected function connect($timeout = 5, $attempts = 10)
  {
    return $this->stream = parent::connect($timeout, $attempts);
  }

  protected function isConnected() 
  {
    return $this->stream && stream_get_meta_data($this->stream)['eof'];
  }
}


class MyStreamingBird extends \OwlyCode\StreamingBird
{
  public function createStreamReader($method)
  {
    $oauth = new \OwlyCode\StreamingBird\Oauth($this->consumerKey,
      $this->consumerSecret, $this->oauthToken, $this->oauthSecret);
    return new MyStreamReader(new \OwlyCode\StreamingBird\Connection(), $oauth, $method);
  }
}


$bird = new MyStreamingBird($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oauthToken, $oauthSecret);
$reader = $bird->createStreamReader(StreamReader::METHOD_FILTER); // ...

$reader->isConnected();
```

You can also make a class based on `\OwlyCode\StreamingBird`, which has access to the stream as well. However, you'll have to keep track of these streams, because it's a factory method.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use socket_get_status after all if you just make a small addition in the package itself.

**These two functions are in streamreader class, socket handler is available here.**

```
public function consume(callable $handler)
{
    $this->running = true;
    while ($this->running) { /// while $this->running is true socket will try to reconnect always. 
        $this->consumeOnce($handler);
    }
}
    protected function consumeOnce(callable $handler)
    {
        $this->connection = $this->connect();
        $lastStreamActivity = time();
        $this->connection->read(function ($tweet) use (&$lastStreamActivity, $handler) {
            $idle = (time() - $lastStreamActivity);
            $this->monitor->stat('max_idle_time', $idle);
            $this->monitor->stat('idle_time', $idle);
            $this->monitor->stat('tweets', 1);
            $lastStreamActivity = time();
            call_user_func($handler, $tweet, $this->monitor);
        });
        $this->connection->close();
    }
```

**In connection class you have the socket handler available so you can grab socket status when trying to read data from socket. Below is a slightly modified read function**

```
public function read(callable $callback, $timeout = 5)
        {
            $this->pool = [$this->connection];
    stream_set_timeout($this->connection, $timeout);
    $info = stream_get_meta_data($this->connection);
            while ($this->connection !== null && !feof($this->connection) && stream_select($this->pool, $fdw, $fde, $timeout) !== false && $info['timed_out']!==true) {
                // @todo safeguard no tweets but connection OK. (reconnect)
                $this->pool = [$this->connection];
                $chunkInfo = trim(fgets($this->connection));
                if (!$chunkInfo) {
                    continue;
                }
                $len = hexdec($chunkInfo) + 2;
                $streamInput = '';
                while (!feof($this->connection)) {
                    $streamInput .= fread($this->connection, $len-strlen($streamInput));
                    if (strlen($streamInput)>=$len) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $this->buffer .= substr($streamInput, 0, -2);
                $data = json_decode($this->buffer, true);
                if ($data) {
                    call_user_func($callback, $data);
                    $this->buffer = '';
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [implementation of class `StreamingBird`](https://github.com/OwlyCode/StreamingBird/blob/master/src/StreamingBird.php#L33), you see you can easily create the streamreader instance yourself, with full control over the connection:

```
namespace \OwlyCode\StreamingBird;
// Let's instantiate the Oauth signature handler
$oauth = new Oauth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oauthToken, $oauthSecret);
// Let's create our own Connection object!
$connection = new Connection();

// And here comes our Reader
$reader = new StreamReader($connection, $oauth, StreamReader::METHOD_FILTER);
$reader->setTrack(['hello'])
       ->consume(function ($tweet) {
            echo '------------------------' . "\n";
            echo $tweet['text'] . "\n";
       });

// Voilà
print_r(socket_get_status($connection->connection));
```

The [`Connection` object stores the socket resource in a public property `$connection`](https://github.com/OwlyCode/StreamingBird/blob/master/src/Connection.php#L13):

```
public $connection;
// ... 
@$this->connection = fsockopen($host, $port, $errNo, $errStr, $timeout);
```